# How to deselect a radio input?

Tags: javascript, input

I would like to uncheck a radio input without necessarily being forced to check another one. What would be the simplest way to do this?

```
        <C.SingleCard>
            <h2>Pizza</h2>
            <div>
                <hr />
                <h3>Flavors</h3>
                <hr />
            </div>
            <div>
                <h4>Pepperoni</h4>
                <input type="radio" name='flavor' />
            </div>
            <div>
                <h4>Chicken</h4>
                <input type="radio"  name='flavor' />
            </div>
            <div>
                <h4>Bacon</h4>
                <input type="radio"  name='flavor'  />
            </div>
            <div>
                <button>Add</button>
            </div>
        </C.SingleCard>
```

Comment: Add another radio button? One that means ‘no value’?

Comment: Yes, 'no value'

Comment: For your example above, perhaps a ‘cheese only’ option. Also, checkboxes would be nice because some people want more than one topping on their pizza.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to do this is to try this:

```
<C.SingleCard>
            <h2>Pizza</h2>
            <div>
                <hr />
                <h3>Flavors</h3>
                <hr />
            </div>
            <div>
                <h4>Pepperoni</h4>
                <input type="radio" name='flavor' onClick="click()"/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h4>Chicken</h4>
                <input type="radio"  name='flavor' onClick="click()"/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h4>Bacon</h4>
                <input type="radio"  name='flavor' onClick="click()"/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button>Add</button>
            </div>
</C.SingleCard>

<script>
function click() {
    if (this.clicked === true) {
        this.clicked = false
    } else if (this.clicked === false) {
        this.clicked = true
    }
}
</script>
```

But it's always better to use checkboxes if you want users to be able to uncheck without having to check another one.

Comment: In the case of a checkbox, how would I select only one item and not be able to select more than one, for example?

Comment: For example, I tried to put a checkbox and even putting all the inputs with the same name, I can select more than one checkbox

Comment: Hi Routfin, did the above solution work? If it did, it would be better to stick to it for allowing only one selection. If you decide to go ahead with checkboxes, the only way to do this is with the use of jQuery. You can check this blog out https://www.codexworld.com/how-to/allow-only-one-checkbox-to-be-checked-jquery/#:~:text=If%20you%20want%20to%20allow,first%2C%20include%20the%20jQuery%20library.&text=To%20modify%20the%20default%20functionality,user%20to%20select%20multiple%20checkboxes. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Here you can try this logic :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <style></style>
  <body>
    <div>
      <h2>Pizza</h2>
      <div>
        <hr />
        <h3>Flavors</h3>
        <hr />
      </div>
      <div>
        <h4>Pepperoni</h4>
        <input class="radio" type="radio" name="flavor" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <h4>Chicken</h4>
        <input class="radio" type="radio" name="flavor" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <h4>Bacon</h4>
        <input class="radio" type="radio" name="flavor" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <button>Add</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script>
      let radios = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".radio"));
      let bool = true,
        lastRadioIndex;
      for (let item of radios) {
        item.onclick = (ev) => {
          let index = radios.findIndex((elem) => elem == ev.target);

          if (!bool && index == lastRadioIndex) {
            item.checked = false;
            bool = true;
          } else if (bool) {
            bool = false;
          }
          lastRadioIndex = index;
        };
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```